# Declare function from JNI

Tags: java, jvm, java-native-interface

Is there any way to create native function from jni without creating dll? I mean like in python http://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html 
Section 5.4. Extending Embedded Python

I don't want to use dll exported functions.

Regards

Comment: If you don't want to use DLLs or shared libraries, you don't want to use JNI. Can you explain why you want to use JNI?

Comment: I didn't say I don't want to use JNI. I use jvm created inside c++ program like http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17352/JVM-Launcher .

Comment: So you can have the native methods call back to your C++ program provided it implements the method generated by `javah`  IMHO calling Java from C++ is more pain than it's worth and isn't done very often which is possibly why most of the "native" documentation is likely to talk about DLLs.

Comment: Could you give me some examples? I can only call java methods from cpp but not in opposite direction. Using javah means creating dll with exported functions? Thats what I don't want.

Comment: Is there JNI method to create class programaticaly and add static native functions that can be accessable from java?

Comment: It's very complicated to do from C++, but possible. It is beyond most Java developers with ten years development experience to do in Java btw.  What is not possible is to call native methods which have not already been implemented in C with predetermined names. javah will tell you what the names should be, but you can work it out.

Comment: It is far simpler to write the Java classes and compile them.  You can do this without altering any of the code in the JVM.

Answer (score 1):

You can embbed VM in a native application, call into Java from C/C++ then callback from Java back into C/C++. See the [Invocation API in JNI documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/invocation.html#wp9502). This way there is no need for dynamic linking (DLLs). You can also dynamically generate classes in runtime by generating bytecode with native methods (e.g. with [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/)) and then registering whatever C/C++ function pointers you need with [RegisterNatives](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html#registering_native_methods).

Answer (score 0):

technically it is possible.

Around 6 or 8 years ago I saw a C++ implementation (it was at codeproject site presented), which created a JVM and did access Java classes. Isn't very popular, for very good reasons, are to many to enumerate here, but is possible.

I would strongly recommend to do the other side, exactly what you don't want: java invoke the dll or so, but to many reasons, but is up to you...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna) does what you want?